# ios-ntp crash broken pipe

Tags: ios, objective-c

My App uses the opensource `ios-ntp` framework (https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp)
So far, it works fine my Apps uses the commands available to calculate the time difference between the system time and network time and applies this to a localnotification.

However, the app crashes if the connection gets lost, I think this is because the NTP socket connection does not get closed after time syncing?

This is what happens:

1) Turn the App on, let it sync with the timeserver then put the App in background mode

2) Turn Airplane mode on, or just wait a while until the connection changes from WiFi to 3G e.d.

3) Reopen the App, it will crash and return the following:

```
Jun 25 09:00:11 iPhone App[460] <Warning>:             NetworkClock|*** application -> Foreground
Jun 25 09:00:11 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:nl.app[0x8f48][460]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:nl.app[0x8f48]) Exited abnormally: Broken pipe: 13
Jun 25 09:00:11 iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:nl.app[0x8f48]' exited abnormally with signal 13: Broken pipe: 13
```

How should I prevent this? Is there a way to close the connection after syncing with the NTP server since I can't find one.

AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self checkForReachability];
}
```

Comment: Signal 13 is this -> 13    SIGPIPE      terminate process    write on a pipe with no reader.  It probably means you are trying to write into an invalid socket.  Show your code when the app comes into the foreground.

Comment: That doesn't help much.  What are you doing inside checkForReachability.  Also, what are you doing when the app goes into the background.  Are you closing the socket?

Comment: @borrrden No I'm not since I don't know how to, it seems that there is some automatic code in the framework because it reports   `NetworkClock application -> Background` - `[self checkForReachability];` just checks if there is an internet connection, don't think that's the issue though.

Comment: Any updates on this question. am also having this same issue.